# Algorithm to calculate Polylogarithm

Tags: numerical-algorithms

In my code i want to solve the [Fermi-Dirac-Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_integral) numerically. This can be achieved with a [Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Actually I'm coding in `C#`, so my function to calculate this polylogarithm looks like that:

```
public double PolyLog(double s, double z)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 1e5; k++)
        sum += Math.Pow(z, k) / Math.Pow(k, s);
    return sum;
}
```

This actually does it's job pretty well for values `|z| < 1`.
However, I need to calculate the polylogarithm also for values that are bigger than 1.

**Is there any code, that calculates polylogarithms for |z|>1?**
Probably this would be done by any kind of analytic continuation.
Although, I'm using `C#`, I don't care about the language. I can easily translate any code to `C#`.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/124418/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3634689/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 4):

["Note on fast polylogarithm computation"](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/crandall/papers/Polylog.pdf) by R. E. Crandall contains an explicit algorithm for computing the polylogarithm.

Comment: Thanks to both of you who asked and answered this question!  I have implemented *algorithm 2.1* from that paper, and found that for negative `n` and `|z| >= 2` it tries to compute a negative factorial in equation 1.3, and equation 1.5 requires many iterations for negative `n`.  I replaced equation 1.5 with an expansion based on Eulerian numbers, and only use equation 1.3 for positive `n`.  I'm well outside my depth with this, but my code is here, for the curious: https://github.com/mike-bourgeous/mb-math/blob/227309c9b91546fd89e80ea4cdc010cee468bda7/lib/mb/m/special_functions.rb#L7-L63